# tcpdump filter to capture only egress frames from a NIC standpoint

Tags: tcpdump

Is there a tcpdump filter to capture, from the NIC's perspective, egress frames only?

We have a MAC flapping situation due to a layer 2 loop, so I need to be able to capture inbound or outbound from a layer 1 perspective, regardless of what the src/dst IP/MAC is.

Answer (score 1):

[-Q direction](https://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html) or [--direction=direction](https://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html)

Choose send/receive direction direction for which packets should be captured. Possible values are `in`, `out` and `inout`. Not available on all platforms